# Convergence of relative sum of iid random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to find some reference with respect to the following problem:
Given $n$ iid **positive** random variables $(X_i)_{i\leq n}$ of mean $E(X)>0$ and variance $V(X)$.

I wanted to know if there were some properties on the random variable:
$Z_n = \frac{\sum (X_i  -E(X))}{\sum X_i}$. 
Specifically I am interested in its convergence speed, something like the law of large numbers or Chebychev/Chernoff bounds. If it does not involve $V(X)$ it's even better.

Anyone knows where to look?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$
Z_n = \frac{\sum_1^n (X_i  -E(X))}{\sum_1^n X_i} 
= 1 - \frac{\mu}{\sum_1^n X_i/n},
$$ where $\mu = E(X)$.

Then, 
$$ Z = \lim_\limits{n \rightarrow \infty}  Z_n 
=_d 1 - \frac{\mu}{G_n }, 
$$

where the limit is in distribution, with r.v. $G_n =_d N( \mu, \sigma^2/n)$

This convergence in distribution implies directly:
$$
P(|G_n - \mu| >\delta ) = 2\Phi( -\frac{\delta \sqrt{n}}{\sigma})
$$

Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability (to the same constant), that is, $G_n \rightarrow_P \mu$.

Then, $Z_n$ converges to zero with rate $1/n$ for a fixed error (as can be seen from the simple Wiki proof of weak LLN using Chebyshev inequality).

Comment: Thanks, but this is just a rewrite of the same equation. Can we say something then about the convergence speed of this new RV?